# Dynamic binding to XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, dynamic

I'm working on a WPF app which loads its data from an XML file. One of the nodes in this XML file is a path to another XML file. The path to this file is different for each item. Ideally I'd like to dynamically bind to this second file and populate a grid with its data so that when the user selects another item from the first XML, the details from the second XML are displayed too.

Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible. what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably bind the `DataContext` of the details grid to the path of the file and use a [`Binding.Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) to load an `XmlDocument` or `XmlDataProvider` from that, or i would create a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which does that.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll be toying with this today.